# Diff and "--GTYPE-group-format"

Tags: unix, command-line, diff

I have two files I want to compare with `diff`. Changed lines should get a prefix "U", new lines "I" and deleted ones "D":

file1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

file2:

```
1
2a
4
5
6

diff --old-group-format="D %<" \
--new-group-format="I %>" \
--changed-group-format="U %>" \
--unchanged-group-format="" file1 file2
```

The output is:

```
U 2a
I 6
```

But where is

```
D 3
```

?

Answer (score 7):

It's sort of the way diff groups things. In your `changed` group, you're printing the new change and not the old, which would be

```
U 2
3
```

So the groupings that diff sees is:

```
`1 -> 1` unchanged
`2,3 -> 2a` changed
`4,5 -> 4,5` unchanged
`  -> 6` new
```

In order for diff to group a match as "old", there has to be an unchanged before and after. So if file2 was like this:

```
1a
2
4
5
6
```

And you ran the same diff command, you'd get this:

```
U 1a
D 3
I 6
```

Because there is a `2 -> 2` and `4 -> 4` that is unchanged so the missing 3 gets grouped as "old".

Comment: Okay there has to be an unchanged before and after but I don't have control over the ordering. Is there another way to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Jon Lin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098857/45375):

While you can't use the `--<gtype>-group-format` options directly to *always* show deleted lines (as explained in Jon's answer), the `--side-by-side` (`-y`) output-format option *does* contain the desired information, and you can use `awk` to reformat it as desired:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side file1 file2 | 
 awk -F'\t+' '$2 ~ / +\|/ { print "U " $3 }
              $2 ~ / +</  { print "D " $1 }
              $2 ~ / +>/  { print "I " $3 }'
```

With your sample files this yields:

```
U 2a
D 3
I 6
```

which the above `awk` command produced from the following `--side-by-side` output:

```
2                                 | 2a
3                                 <
                                  > 6
```